# Adding class to only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help adding a class to a div if is has an image to it.

```
<div class="large-6 columns check-Div">
  <div class="custom-table">
    <div class="text">
      <?php echo $latestimage; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-table-box">
      <?php echo $table; ?>
    </div>
  </div><!-- end custom-table -->
</div>
```

```js
if ($j(".large-6.columns.check-Div > .custom-table-box:contains('size-full')")) {
  $j('.large-6.columns.check-Div').addClass("hasImage");
}
```

The jQuery above is adding the `hasImage` class to all of the divs but I only want it to apply when there is a div that contains a image. Is there a way to do it singularly? Or by parent? I have tried but I'm a little lost.

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped. This is why I love this place. Cheers and happy weekend ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using jquery no need to add if condition

```
jQuery(".custom-table-box:has(img)").parents(".check-Div").addClass("hasImage");
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: You did and now I can get on with the day. Have a great weekend!!

Answer (score 2):

CSS **:has** selector is what you are looking for (here for a direct descendant)

```
$('div:has(> img)').addClass("hasImage") //jquery way
```

or just in css (but this would require a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-polyfills), as its in Level 4, which is draft currently)

```
div:has(> img) {
   border-color: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

**JSfiddle** here: https://jsfiddle.net/y6gtt2vg/1/

---

**Browser support**

About CSS Selector Compatibility

Regardless of a browser's support of CSS selectors, all selectors listed at api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ will return the correct set of elements when passed as an argument of the jQuery function.

https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @mayersdesign unfortunately not, otherwise this would be the perfect solution

Comment: When used as jQuery selector, then jQuery is doing the selection, not the browser...

Comment: The edit makes this much more interesting (using as a jQuery selector)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by removing the `if` statement and just adding the class based on the `:has` selector:

```
$j('.large-6.columns.check-Div:has(img)').addClass('hasImage');
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

For clarity I have added additional background color

```js
$(".custom-table").children("div").each(function(item,index) {
  $(this).has("img").css("background-color", "red"); // Comment it if not needed
  $(this).has("img").addClass("hasImage");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="large-6 columns check-Div">
    <div class="custom-table">
      <div class="text">
        xyz<img />
      </div>
      <div class="custom-table-box">
      abc
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are welome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('.large-6 .columns .check-Div div:has(img)').addClass('hasImage');
```

Comment: Your selector has some major issues

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using id.

```
<div id="addImg" class="large-6 columns check-Div">
                  <div class="custom-table">
                  <div class="text">
                    <?php echo $latestimage; ?>
                  </div>


                    <div class="custom-table-box">
                      <?php echo $table; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div><!-- end custom-table -->
                </div>
```

`if ($j(".large-6.columns.check-Div > .custom-table-box:contains('size-full')")) {
                $j('#addImg').addClass(".hasImage");//also missing . for class
              }`